# PHP variables not retaining value when trying to assign to a form field

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Thanks in advance for your help.  I am new to PHP.  I have done a lot of learning to get to this point, but I am currently stuck.

I have a form with a 'fields-section' and a 'proof-section' that has 3 buttons - proof, edit and send.  Initially, the 'fields-section' is displayed and the 'proof-section' is hidden. Of the 3 buttons, the 'proof' button is visible while the other 2 are not. After the form is completed and 'proof' is clicked, the fields are validated, some fields are transformed into Hebrew and a proof is presented to the user by hiding the 'fields-section' and showing the 'proof-section'. Here the 'edit' and 'send' buttons are available and the 'proof' button is hidden. I am integrating this form within a Wordpress page template.

**I am finding that the PHP variables do not have any value and I don't understand why.**
If I change `echo htmlspecialchars($line1);` to

```
if(isset($_POST['line1'])){
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['line1']);
}
```

It works...but this solution doesn't work for `$line1_hebrew` because this is a calculated field.  I deleted unnecessary code below to keep it short.

Below is my code from the Wordpress template:

```
<?php
include "hebrew-memorial-creator.php";

add_action( 'genesis_after_loop', 'em_form');

/**
 * Output the form to the page
 *
 */
function em_form() {
?>

<div id="hebrew-memorial-creator">
<form name="hebrewMemorialForm" action="" method="POST">
    <div id="field_section">
        <div>
            <label for="line1">Line 1: </label><input type="text" name="line1" id="line1" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($line1);?>" size="50" maxlength=40 />
            <input type="hidden" name="line1_hebrew" id="line1_hebrew" value="<?php htmlspecialchars($line1_hebrew);?>" />
        </div>
            .... deleted some fields here
    </div><!--field-section-->
    <input type="submit" id="proof_button" name= "proof_button" value="PROOF">
    <input type="submit" id="edit_button" name="edit_button" value="EDIT"> 
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="submit_button" value="SEND">
    <div id="proof_section">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($proof);?>
    </div><!--proof-section-->
</form>
</div><!--hebrew-memorial-creator-->

<?php 
} // end function em_form
    genesis();
?>
```

Below is my code from hebrew-memorial-creator.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['line1'])) { $line1 = $_POST['line1']; }
    ... deleted code for other fields...

    if(isset($_POST['proof_button'])) { 

        $formerrors = false;

        // validate fields
        // email address is required
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo 'email error';
            $emailErr = 'Please enter a valid email address';
            $formerrors = true;
        }

        if (! ($formerrors)) {

            // for line1 - line4, create line1_hebrew - line4_hebrew - converting lowercase letters to Hebrew characters
            // and write to hidden form fields
            $line1_hebrew = convert($line1);
            ... deleted code for additional fields

            // all fields validated
            // show proof fields and submit/proof buttons
            $proof = '<div class="bronze"><p style="font-size: 36px; text-align:center;">HERE IS YOUR PROOF :</p>';
            $proof .= '<p>Line1: ' . htmlspecialchars($line1) . ' ==> ' . htmlspecialchars($line1_hebrew) . '</p>';
            ... deleted code for other fields
            $proof .= '</div>';
            $proof .= "<script>
                $('#field_section').hide();
                $('#proof_section').show();
                $('#proof_button').hide();
                $('#edit_button').show();
                $('#submit_button').show();
                $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
                </script>";
`               // curious if anyone has a better solution to hiding/showing field`        
        } // end if no errors  
        return;
    } // end proof button pressed

    if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {

        ....deleted formatting of mail variables
        mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        wp_redirect( get_site_url() . '/thank-you');
    } // end send button pressed

    // replacing any lowercase characters with their hebrew character equivalent
    function convert($line) {

        if (($line == '') || ($line == ' ')) {
            return $line;
        }

        $newLine = "";

        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($line); $i++) {
            //$character = substr($line, $i, 1); 
            $character = $line[$i];
            ... deleted code
        } // end for

        return $newLine;

    } // end function convert

    ?>
```

Comment: Didn't spend too much time going into this, but it could be a scope issue, try declaring the var higher or mark it global.

Comment: It is indeed a scope issue. In your `em_form()` function nowhere do you define `$line1_hebrew`. Make sure you  [turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). PHP should have given you some sort of warning that the variable was undefined.

Comment: Thanks to both you for your fast response @Wobbles and Mike...adding the global variable to the em_form() function did the trick!